# Keeping Docker Containers Current

Tags: git, github, docker

Let's say that I have several Docker containers. Each is serving code that was originally pulled from a remote Git repository when the container was started. However, now some of the containers are serving code that is behind the remote master branch. I want to get all of them up-to-date.

I realize that I could probably run `docker exec -it [container_id] bash` and then manually `git pull` inside of each of my containers, but that does not seem like a very scalable or practical option.

Is there an existing method for automating the code-pulls of my Docker containers? Are webhooks the proper way of going about this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use web hooks assuming that you have a reachable endpoint. I prefer building new docker images when your repo is updated but going with your approach you can consider something like:

1. Let's call your containers A, B, and C.
2. Setup a new container W that exposes the web hook, and mounts volumes for A, B, and C. Your git packages will be cloned into those volumes.
3. `docker run` A, B, and C with `--volumes-from W`
4. When W receives an update, it does a git pull on the appropriate package, automatically updating the code that the container sees.
5. W might need to send a restart signal to the container as appropriate.

Comment: Is W essentially a master container that exposes webhooks for each of the separate containers A, B, and C (indirectly through the volumes)? Additionally, will `--volumes-from W` allow each container to have access to A, B, and C's repositories?

Comment: Correct on both counts.

Comment: You can always move W's functionality into A, B, and C directly of course if that makes more sense.